# Download image to sqlite database with Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm building an iphone app that will include 200 images I've scraped from a website, which will be randomly shown to the user.  I'm trying to store those images in a sqlite database with Python.  (Note:  In my research so far, I've learned that this may not be the best way to achieve my goal, and I'm asking about that in this linked question [Use images in an iOS app from a database without internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113535/use-images-in-an-ios-app-from-a-database-without-internet-connection).  I'm still curious as to what I'm doing wrong).

```
    response = requests.get(picture_url) #url is definitely correct
    picture = sqlite3.Binary(response.content)
    con = sqlite3.connect(db_filename)
    cursor = con.cursor()
    sql = '''CREATE TABLE member_data(id integer primary key autoincrement, picture BLOB, name TEXT);'''
    cursor.execute(sql)
    sql = '''INSERT INTO member_data (picture, name) VALUES ("{}", "{}",)'''.format(photo, member_name)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    con.commit()
```

The rest of the database works correctly (the text fields).  I'm using Sublime and getting the output `[Decode error - output not utf-8]` but I'm not sure what to do with that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first mistake in your code is when you write...:

```
INSERT INTO member_data (picture, name, email, link)
```

when you've just created table `member_data` to have fields `picture` and `name` but **not** `email` or `link` -- and then you're trying to format only two values into that SQL string.  I suspect you're **not** showing us your actual code but a mistaken attempt at simplifying it.

A much deeper mistake you're making is using string formatting to prepare your sql statement, rather than place-holders as you should.

So, change:

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO member_data (picture, name, email, link) VALUES ("{}", "{}",)'''.format(photo, member_name)
con.cursor().execute(sql)
```

into:

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO member_data (picture, name) VALUES (?, ?)'''
cursor.execute(sql, (photo, member_name))
```

(you already have a perfectly good cursor, why bother making another?-)

Comment: You are correct that these errors were caused by incorrect simplification--I have edited the post.  The place-holder correction is a good tip; I had struggled with that.  However, I don't think any of these errors account for my stated problem, unless I misunderstand.

Comment: @thumbtackthief have you tried w/the placeholders?  Please do so and edit your Q accordingly -- I don't think your problem will persist.

Comment: I don't understand how, but that indeed fixes it!  Thanks!

Comment: @thumbtackthief, the `how` is based on how interpolation of `?` place-holders (that can stand for different types, including blobs in this case) work, versus **string** interpolation, which, guess what!, only works for **strings**, i.e, **human readable text** (very specifically *not* including binary large objects, aka BLOBs, such as images).