# Use images in an iOS app from a database without internet connection

Tags: ios, swift

I have a SQLite database consisting of 200 photos that I intend to use in an iOS app (only one will be rendered at a time, per view).

It's my understanding from research that storing these images in a database is not best practice.

I understand how I could store the URL (and that would solve some of the programming problems I'm having) but I don't really want the app to demand Internet connectivity.

Is there another way, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Package the images in the app's resource bundle along with the (read-only) database file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [documents or library directory inside of the application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) package to store your images. Your database, if necessary, would have only reference to the names of those files.

Comment: So I should just download the files to a local directory, then include that whole folder in supporting files?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you don't store an undefined number of images locally, as and generally speaking you don't want your app to eat space. (its just a bad thing).

I'm thinking of profiles pictures, or blog post pictures or something like that. Don't save them.

I suggest that when you have an internet connection, you load them with their URL in the most classic way and cache them. This will have the same effect as saving them, but won't take disk space. iOS will take care of releasing it when necessary (too much data to handle). Then you just re-download it.

If you happen to be in an offline environnment and the user doesn't have the image cached, then at that point I would use a placeholder (like a big ? with a grey background or something similar).

And to be clear i'll repeat myself : 
Unless you're talking about a static number of reccurent images (like buttons or backgrounds of your app), I suggest you dont' store those files locally.

Profiles pics, even small, represent a huge amount of data for a lot of users (with 2000+ contacts which happens to be more frequent than i thought).

Also, if it's AddressBook pictures, you can simply store a reference to them since they're already store somewhere on the iPhone.

Comment: I dont agree with you :) You can simply manage it , I'm developing app like Instagram  , so i 'm saving locally only the past 7 days data , and all older data is being deleted . And you can check the folder sizes and if it greater than X , delete the oldest one , make it dynamic . So the user exprinece is much better than re-download it